# Template field in ext js

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I have the need to create the custom form field which need to works like TemplateColumn in gridPanel.
This custom form field will render multiple field in data model using the provided template just like TemplateColumn.

Since i only want to display data using this custom form field in the form panel so i try to extend the display field, but it only accept 1 data field in the model.

How could I make the custom form field accept value from 2 or more data field in model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do a two way bind with these fields or just display the data?

Comment: I just want to display the data only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can bind to several fields and also included text

```
  bind: {
      value: "{rec.field1} - static text -> {rec.field2}"
    }
```

feel free to add a fiddle to show what you want to do if this is not correct.